# Is build completion triggers also avaiable in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

There is a new Feature in VSTS that allows to chain together related builds:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/apr-03-vsts#chain-related-builds-together-using-build-completion-triggers

Is this also available in TFS 2018?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't be available until TFS2019 (Azure DevOps Server). See Apr 3rd entry on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/

Comment: Try the marketplace. Has some extensions to help workaround i.e. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=megoels.buildchain

Comment: @MarkusMauch this answer should be marked as "answer" for your question.

Comment: @ColinB: Thanks, I'll give it a try.